# Undefined control sequence in Latex using programming code

Tags: errors, code

**Problem:**

Getting the error message `Undefined control sequence. (\end{document}..).` This occurs when I include the following code that prints out formatted programming code. If I remove this code the issue goes away.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{studentlitteratur} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\mdfdefinestyle{mdlistingstyle}{} 
\mdtheorem[style=mdlistingstyle]{sourcecode}[chapter]{Kodexempel} 
\begin{document} 
\part{Title} 
\begin{sourcecode} 
\end{sourcecode} 
\lipsum[1-3] 
\begin{sourcecode} 
\end{sourcecode} 
\end{document}
```

**.cls content available here:** http://pastebin.com/w1HVnM9L

**.sty content available here:** http://pastebin.com/YGTedA7q

**Error message:**

```
./studentlitteratur.tex:13: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \bbl@restore@actives delz
                                         i\protect \hspace  {0.5em} title
l.13 \end{document}
```

**Desired outcome:**

To remove the error message and achieve correct code.

Comment: It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: @Andrew Like I initially conveyed, the document is quite complex and it would take quite a while to include all the necessary code to make a MWE. I have tried to add more information in form of the error message I get. I include MWE by default whenever possible.

Comment: What package does the `sourcecode` environment come from?

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin I have now included that information.

Comment: Have you? I don't think any of the known packages there include that environment, and how are we supposed to know what is in `studentlitteratur-thm.sty`, or for that matter `studentlitteratur.cls`?

Comment: Do the error occur if you only include that one snippet in a document? Can you reproduce it with a standard documentclass (e.g. `article`)? If the answer is yes to both of those, you're halfway to the MWE already, all you need to do is clean up the preamble, and extract the necessary parts from `studentlitteratur-thm.sty`.

Comment: Also, I don't see the `HTML5`, `CSS` and `JavaScript` drivers in the `lstdrvrs.pdf` manual of the `listings` package. And I don't see that package either.

Everything works fine without using them or the `sourcecode` envo.

So the problem is (hopefully) either with that envo or the drivers, and both are defined somewhere in `studentlitteratur-thm.sty`, I presume.

Extracting those is probably sufficient to produce an MWE.

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin I have extracted all code for `studentlitteratur-thm.sty` and added it to the beginning of this question.

Comment: Pardon. I meant `studentlitteratur.cls`.
As the name suggests `studentlitteratur-thm.sty` contains only theorem-related code.

Comment: First a small apology, I didn't notice `\mdtheorem[style=mdlistingstyle,theoremseparator={}]{sourcecode}...,` in the code you have posted. That does require the `mdframed` package though, which is not present anywhere I think. Perhaps in the class file.

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin Can't add it here, it's too long. So here it is: http://codeshare.io/nUApU

Comment: I managed to compile your code using the documentclass you provided. Some colours, `mdframed` and the language parsers are still missing. Apart from these there seem to be no other problems. So you are probably omitting something crucial from your preamble. I suggest you delete everything except the problematic `sourcecode` from your document, and keep the preamble intact. Does it compile? Work down from there producing an MWE. Also: try commenting the `lstlisting` options. Does it compile?

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin Managed to reproduce the issue with this "minimal" example: http://codeshare.io/hfLTg.

Comment: If your question relies on external links, it is not going to help other users when those links change. There are cases in which it really isn't possible to produce an MWE worth the M, but such cases are extremely rare. Note, too, that an error message is much more useful with the code to produce it. For one thing, the line number may possibly indicate the source of the problem or, at least, provide some clue. (Not necessarily the case but often.)

Comment: @cfr What is your recommendation when there is a limitation of how much code lines you can include on SE?

Comment: Reduce the example. I can provoke the same error with `\documentclass{studentlitteratur}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\figureversion}[1]{}
\usepackage{listings}
\mdfdefinestyle{mdlistingstyle}{}
\mdtheorem[style=mdlistingstyle]{sourcecode}[chapter]{Kodexempel}
\begin{document}
\part{Title}
\begin{sourcecode}
\end{sourcecode}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{sourcecode}
\end{sourcecode}
\end{document}`. I had to define `\figureversion` for some reason, and uncomment some font packages from the class file because I don't have them (`MinionPro`, `MnSymbol`, `MyriadPro`). (Doesn't help for the class file.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks, I have followed your recommendation and done some cleaning up. I have also switched the code to pastebin.com with no expiration time unlike codeshare.io to address cfr's concerns.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. great work. Even minimalER: `\documentclass{studentlitteratur}\usepackage{lipsum}\usepackage{listings}\begin{document}\part{Part}\lipsum\end{document}` with the same caveat for fonts. So ultimately the problem has nothing to do with `sourcecode`. The definition of `\part` messes up _something_.

Comment: @PaoloBrasolin Removing sourcecode will not generate an error message. Having one segment of begin/end of sourcecode does not produce any errors either. However, having two segments of begin/end of sourcecode seems to generate the error message.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with @PaoloBrasolin's example - no need for `sourcecode` at all.

Comment: It is an interaction with `babel`, I think. Commenting out the call to `babel` also allows compilation. Probably just need to turn active characters off and on appropriately?

Comment: `listings` seem to have some influence as well, after messing around with the class file, I can get to https://bitbucket.org/snippets/torbjornt/qRExe

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. Sorry. I meant it is an interaction with `babel` as well as `listings` and `\part{}` from Paolo's MWE. I just mentioned `babel` because it is hidden in the class file rather than explicit in the MWE. Using TikZ's `babel` library doesn't help, though.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You mean the code you posted reproduces the error without the non-standard class?

Comment: @cfr Yes, it does. I isolated the same parts from `studentlitteratur` not a minute ago. We finally have an MWE.

Comment: The current error points to line 13, which is `\end{document}`. Perhaps you should remove all auxiliary files and try to compile again.

Comment: @Werner I just did and it points out that the error is at line 295 in my working file and that line is `\begin{sourcecode}[\HTML~\PLUS~\PHP]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An MWE (thanks @TorbjørnT.) reproducing your error is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
  \makeatletter
  \makepsmarks{headings}{%
  \def\partmark##1{\markboth{%
      \partname~\thepart\hspace{0.5em} ##1}{}}%
  }
  \makeevenhead{headings}{\MakeLowercase{\leftmark}}{}{}
  \pagestyle{headings}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
\part{Title}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

*You too* could have extorted this from your custom document class by mutilation. In fact, the indented lines are taken nearly verbatim from it.

There are various ways to make this example compile:

- omitting `babel`
- omitting `listings`
- omitting the `~`
- omitting `\MakeLowercase`

The exact same error can be produced in a different and simpler context with a shorter example that has exactly the same behaviour:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % the language is irrelevant
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\MakeLowercase{A~Z}
\end{document}
```

A simple solution is replacing `~` with its synonymous `\nobreakspace`, as in:

```
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
\def\partmark##1{\markboth{%
    \partname\nobreakspace \thepart\hspace{0.5em} ##1}{}}%
}
```

This will *probably* fix your document class.

A more elegant solution would require knowing exactly how `listings` and `babel` are interacting, i.e. studying their source code. I will not do that. I've skimmed the code of `listings` and there seem to be some comments related to the behaviour of the `~` character, in case you want to dive into it.